# unable to read property list from file, Info.plist issue when I use Mapbox sdk in my app

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, error-handling, info.plist

im facing an issue in one of my flutter apps. Im was using MapBox-SDK plugin but when I tested the app on IOS, it asked me to update my Mapbox-sdk to some version (which I did using pop install command). Now after everything, I am facing new errors in my info.plist file. I forgot to take a backup of my old info.plist file. 
Anyways, the new info.plist is:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<string>YES</string>
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
<key>MGLMapboxAccessToken</key>
<string>Mapbox-key-not-visible</string>
<true/>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>project1</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>  
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</plist
```

the error im facing while building up the app is:

ERROR:

```
Users/apple/flutter-practice/Project-Casky/casky/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List       error: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 10 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
Xcode build done.                                           24.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/apple/flutter-practice/Project-  Casky/casky/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed.  (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator  platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS  Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in  the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

GUYS I can't find a solution to this. Kindly help me in anyway possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have value for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and I guess this is the problem

Comment: @Dimitar You're a savior!

Answer (score 5):

The error `error: unable to read property list from file: Info.plist` is usually caused by missing config on the plist file. As previously mentioned in the comments, you need to have a value set on `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`. More details are explained in the [package's docs](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl#ios).

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>[Your explanation here]</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because the Info.plist file was poorly formatted. It hasn't to do with XML format, because when I tried to find if that file was correctly formatted according to XML rules, it was ok, but when I tried to open the .plist file as a property list, I realized Xcode couldn't read it, so I added my keys using the property list utility, not the "code view".

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem with a newly imported Flutter project. After some debugging, it seems like the issue was caused by a corrupt GoogleService-Info.plist file! Dunno why and how it was corrupted, because I have newly imported and existing project.

To solve this problem, you can follow those steps;

Open your project in XCode
delete the existing GoogleService-Info.plist file
download the original one from Firebase
then reimport/re-copy this file into your project
When this is done, run flutter clean then try running it in iOS Simulator

This worked for me, hope it solves your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by including `<string/>` after each `<key>...</key>` like this :

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string /> 

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string /> 

<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string />
```